# kotlin Flow is not updating realtime

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, kotlin-flow

I have a flow within an interface, and I'm trying to collect values in the ViewModel, but the collect operation isn't being triggered. Can anyone help me figure out what I might be doing wrong?

I am injecting using dagger hilt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RealtimeListenerModule {

    @Provides
    fun bindingFunction() : RealtimeListener{
        return RealtimeListenerImpl()
    }

}
```

```
interface RealtimeListener {
    val user: Flow<User?>
}
```

```
class RealtimeListenerImpl : RealtimeListener {
    
    private val _userData = MutableStateFlow<User?>(null)
    override val user: Flow<User?> = _userData
    
    //this function will trigger when any events comes from firebase and i tested events are firing fine        
    fun updateUserData(){
    _userData.value = it
    }       


}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class UserViewModelImpl
@Inject constructor(private val listener: RealtimeListener) : UserViewModel() {
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            listener.user.collect {
                Log.d("TAG", "trigger $it")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `UserViewModelImpl Log.d("TAG", "trigger $it")` is executing only one Time when `init{}` block called now after some time any new event trigger i am not able to receive value in collect block ,

**also i know that init  block will trigger only once** , i want is that when flow emit value every time i want to update user i need help to achive that  thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Your interface value is "user". The value you override is "userData". Could you try to fix this?

Comment: hey thanks for replay  i just updated question

Comment: Could you try using MutableSharedFlow instead of MutableStateFlow?

Comment: Additionally, I recommend using stateflow instead of flow.

Comment: Sample usage : interface RealtimeListener {
    val user: StateFlow<User?>
}

Comment: seems emmiting is working fine issue is at collect { } side also let me try using StateFlow

Comment: Do you know the difference between StateFlow and shared flow?  You are using flow, this is a cold flow. In short, my suggestion. Whether you use SharedFlow or stateflow. Not in init. You collect it in a fragment or activity.

Comment: I used Flow because I have multiple collectors at the same time, but neither StateFlow, MutableStateFlow, MutableSharedFlow, nor Channel (which is a hot Flow) worked for me. It would be a great help if you could help me update my code.

Comment: also one more thing  i am using jetpack compose.